# "413 Request Entity Too Large" in Nginx with "client_max_body_size" set

Tags: nginx

I am uploading a 26Gb file, but I am getting:

`413 Request Entity Too Large`

I know, this is related to `client_max_body_size`, so I have this parameter set to `30000M`.

```
  location /supercap {
    root  /media/ss/synology_office/server_Seq-Cap/;
    index index.html;
    proxy_pass  http://api/supercap;
  }

  location /supercap/pipe {
    client_max_body_size 30000M;
    client_body_buffer_size 200000k;
    proxy_pass  http://api/supercap/pipe;
    client_body_temp_path /media/ss/synology_office/server_Seq-Cap/tmp_nginx;
  }
```

But I still get this error when the whole file has been uploaded.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't upload that size in one request. You must divide it partitions and send them one-by-one per request.

Answer (score 126):

**Modify NGINX Configuration File**

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Search for this variable: `client_max_body_size`. If you find it, just increase its size to 100M, for example. If it doesn’t exist, then you can add it inside and at the end of http

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Test your nginx config changes.

```
sudo service nginx configtest
```

Restart nginx to apply the changes.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

**Modify PHP.ini File for Upload Limits**

It’s not needed on all configurations, but you may also have to modify the PHP upload settings as well to ensure that nothing is going out of limit by php configurations.

If you are using PHP5-FPM use following command,

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

If you are using PHP7.0-FPM use following command,

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

Now find following directives one by one

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

and increase its limit to 100M, by default they are 8M and 2M.

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Finally save it and restart PHP.

PHP5-FPM users use this,

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

PHP7.0-FPM users use this,

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

It will work fine !!!

Comment: why 100Mb for client_max_body_size in nginx.conf?

Comment: you can put any value according your requirements but 100 mb is sufficient

Comment: but I am uploading up to 30Gb files.

Comment: find a file of maximum size and allow it more than that file

Comment: so why client_max_body_size does not work inside my /location ?

Comment: try this one http://serverfault.com/a/304465/384531

Comment: You can put it to 0 to skip max_bodt_size checks, you can also put it in location but maybe that conflict if you have it in server also ( not sure ) but always you can review documetation about that: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size also be sure than your client_body_temp_path have enough space.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I am marking this answer up (it had -1, no idea why; it's now back to 0). Thanks for this. Specifically "If it doesn’t exist, then you can add it inside and at the end of http" — did the trick nicely. Used this to increase upload size on a MAMP PRO 4 Nginx installation.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why but I had problems until I moved it at the very end of the `http` block.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me on ubuntu

Answer (score 31):

If you're uploading files of that size you should probably just disable the body size check altogether with:

```
client_max_body_size 0;
```

Answer (score 8):

With respect, I'm not sure why you're using http to transfer that much data.  I tend to do my large transfers over ssh

```
//such as:
tar cjf - /path/to/stuff | ssh user@remote-host "cd /path/to/remote/stuff;tar xjf -"
```

...which gives me a bzip-compressed transfer.  But if I needed to do a resumable transfer, I might use sftp, lftp, even rsync.  Any of those (or their derivatives or siblings) is capable of

1. employing an encrypted channel if desired,
2. resuming an interrrupted transfer and
3. compressing the transfer

Only one of those would be an option to you when attempting to upload over http (namely, #1 if you were on https).

I hope you'll look into any of the above or the several other alternatives.

Comment: This has like nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It's only there because the guy is transferring Blueray-scale files over http.  Without having more detail of why someone would want to do this, I judge that guy asking the question would be best served by not successfully answering the question.  I acknowledge that my ignorance of those details is a problem.

Comment: @tom sftp/lftp/rsync ... yeah I'm pretty sure those resume and compress.   But if you're looking at my tar pipe to ssh, yeah that doesn't resume, just compress.

Answer (score 1):

> Add the following line to **`http` or `server` or `location` context** to
> increase the size limit in `nginx.conf`, enter:
>
> ```
> client_max_body_size 100M;
> ```
>
> Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/

The `client_max_body_size` directive can be added in `http`, `server` or `location`.

Note that the max body size will typically be [1.34x larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage) than the file being uploaded. For example, the above limit `100M` will only allow a `74M` file to be uploaded.